# while running the json file in powershell it's working but when I use "convertfrom-json" this error is seen?

Tags: json, azure-powershell

PS C:\Users\Admin> Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\VS Code\config.json"|ConvertFrom-Json
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
At line:1 char:66

- ... -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\VS Code\config.json"|ConvertFrom-Json
- ```
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFrom
    JsonCommand

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this because of the Json content and the version of the PowerShell. The below sample Json that caused the same error as yours when PowerShell version is 5.1.

```
{  
    "employee": {  
        "name":       "sonoo",   
        "salary":      56000,   
        "married":    true,  
    }  
}
```

[image]

Upgrading the PowerShell to 7.2 worked did the trick for me.

[image]

Alternatively, you can remove the last comma from the Json.

```
{  
    "employee": {  
        "name":       "sonoo",   
        "salary":      56000,   
        "married":    true
    }  
}
```

[image]